# why does my for loop miss the first element in the NSMutableArray on which it operates?

Tags: ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I am trying to loop through an NSMutableArray of Persistent IDs of songs in my iPod Library, perform an MPMediaQuery with each ID, and initialize an MPMediaItemCollection from an NSMutableArray of the MPMediaItems returned from the Query. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"songArray viewDidLoad: %@", self.songArray);
for (int i=0; i<[self.songArray count]; i++) {
    NSString *pID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.songArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    MPMediaQuery *cellQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [cellQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:pID
                      forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID]];
    [pID release];
    for (MPMediaItem *item in [cellQuery items]) {
        [tempArray addObject:item];
    }
    [cellQuery release];
    NSLog(@"tempArray: %@", tempArray);
}
self.detailCollection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:tempArray];
NSLog(@"self.detailCollection: %@", self.detailCollection);
```

where self.songArray is the NSMutableArray containing the Persistent IDs. **The code works, except that it misses the first element in self.songArray.** Here is some of my console output, showing self.songArray containing 3 items before the for loop begins and only 1 ID (the last one) being added to the NSMutableArray:

```
2013-06-14 14:55:17.472 green[5579:907] songArray viewDidLoad: (
    14834145442532377094,
    13706522831184680273,
    1223941966377655149
)
2013-06-14 14:55:17.498 green[5579:907] tempArray: (
)
2013-06-14 14:55:17.501 green[5579:907] tempArray: (
)
2013-06-14 14:55:17.505 green[5579:907] tempArray: (
    "<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1146e5a0> 1223941966377655149"
)
2013-06-14 14:55:17.506 green[5579:907] self.detailCollection: <MPMediaItemCollection: 0x11feb140>
```

**EDIT:** Removed [pID release];, now the for loop only misses the *first* element in the array.

Comment: Check whether your query actually finds any items (set a log or breakpoint in the `[tempArray addObject:item];` line).

Comment: I did add an NSLog and it appears [cellQuery items] is empty for all but the last element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing which is wrong in the code is below statement:

```
[pID release];
```

You have not allocated it so you do not need to destroy it. Rest everything looks fine.

One more change is also required. In below line, you are passing pId as string. You should pass it as number.

```
NSNumber *pID = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[[self.songArray objectAtIndex:i] longLongValue]];
[cellQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:pID
                      forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID]];
```

Comment: Interestingly, removing [pID release]; causes the for loop to get all the elements except the _first_ one.

Comment: Any idea why it would miss the first element?
Should I start a new question, since it appears to be a new, unrelated problem?

Comment: Thanks Apurv, I must've discovered the number issue just as you were posting. I managed to get it working with this:

            unsigned long long ullvalue = strtoull([pID UTF8String], NULL, 0);
        NSNumber *UniqueID = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:ullvalue];

And I used the UniqueID as the predicate value. I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @user2136500 great.Enjoy coding..!!